# Can I register in Analytics the users by cookie?

Tags: authentication, cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies, userid

According to the last point of this protocol policy: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy?hl=es-419 
Could I register if a user who is browsing has ever registered on my website while it is not logged in?
I mean, through a cookie I can identify if the user was previously logged in but in this opportunity he returned to the site on the same ip but without being logged in.

Thanks you very much community

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in set a custom dimension with a user level scope. Eg. 'Logged in before'. Next time the user visits the site (with the same browser and same cookies), this session wil also be tracked with the 'Logged in before' custom dimension.
 https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en